# Magento - selective email order confirmation

Tags: php, magento

this could be a tricky question:
I sell a lot of different items on my store to a point where I would like confirmation email to vary according to the item sold.
example, all my Mens item sold would go to one person and all my women items sold go to another person.

Is this possible in magento?

Comment: How do you identify if a item is male or female? What should happen if someone buy both man and woman stuff?

Comment: is there any mandatory option in your site where the user need to fill there sex , so you can distinguish the email on the basis of that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but you'd have to do some work.

Add a new module to your installation, let this module add a new product attribute lets say `email`.

Then in the module rewrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` so you can override the `queueNewOrderEmail` method (I'm assuming you're at 1.9, if not, you should update). Make sure you only override that one method, don't copy the entire file, it'll be less work to check nothing's changed when you upgrade.

In that method you end up replacing `$copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);` with a piece of code that will iterate through your order items and fetch the emails associated with it's products.

That way if an order has items for different people they'll all get an email.